# Using geolocalisation with windows phone, await error

Tags: asynchronous, geolocation, windows-phone-8, async-await

I'm trying to get the current location of an user, but the code show me an error...

```
// try get user location
Geolocator geo = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
geo.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10;
try {
    Geoposition position = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

My problem is that the compiler show me an error at `await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();`

> The 'await' operator can only be used when its containing method or lambda expression is marked with the 'async' modifier.

But from what I have seen, this is the same code [as shown by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I already restart VS12 and the pc (which is a VM but still) and the error is still here...
What's going wrong ?

I also try this and still get the same error:

```
 Geoposition position = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync().asTask<Geoposition>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark your method with async:

```
void **async** themethod()
    {
    // try get user location
    Geolocator geo = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
    geo.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10;
    try {
        Geoposition position = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! 
I just found this. I spend too much time on that simple error ...
Will upvote and close when possible (need 5 minutes)